# Is the shimmering of glowing embers well understood?

Tags: thermodynamics

The embers of a fire glow with an appealing shimmering light.  I've often wondered if this shimmering is well-understood.  For example, it seems to me that the frequency with which the patterns of light move might be explainable somehow; also perhaps the size of the brighter and darker areas.  I have been unable to find anything at all about the physics of shimmering embers on the web.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered it from black body radiation point of view.

Comment: I have no idea how that would be relevant.  This seems to me to be a dynamic problem.  AFAIR (I took thermodynamics in 1976), black body radiation explains static properties.

Comment: But the object is cooling off on one side possibly and heating on the other. Still black body physics explains the glowing. The color of the ember is given by its temperature.

Comment: But you are right. It may not have been studied before and it is a complicated problem probably not solved by black body physics alone.

Comment: My current thought is that you probably could define a time constant, determined by the type of fuel and atmosphere in the fireplace, that would give you the dominant frequency of the shimmering/flickering.  Maybe doesn't matter enough for anyone to have looked into it, as you suggest.

Comment: Thats right. But the fact nobody has looked into it shouldn't dissuade you from tackling the problem.

Comment: Ah, but now that I think of it as turbulent flow, it is a famously hard unsolved problem.  Possibly the most important unsolved problem in classical physics, according to Feynman.  The shimmering is probably the result of turbulent flow of the air over the coals.

Comment: Now you've got me interested!!  But if Feynman thought it was hard its beyond me.  Good luck if you tackle this.